# Edx elastic search data migration from EC2 server to GCP compute engine

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, amazon-ec2

Our team is trying to migrate the Edx platform KOA version from AWS EC2 to GCP Compute engine, Now we are leveraging the Tutor: the Docker-based Open edX distribution. Now the problem is how can we transfer data's of Elasticsearch from EC2 to Compute engine?

We are a noobie here trying all the possible ways to transfer the data